# Doctrine ManyToOne get the ID from the ONE

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a parent and a child table. ManyToOne.
My problem is, that in one case i select directly from the child table with the child ID. And i need the parent id too. The parent ID is saved in the child, because its the reference to the parent. In my case: categories_back_id

I use a query in my repository.But i can not get this categories_back_id column in doctrine. When i select all columns from this table in doctrine - its not there. If i select all in phpMyAdmin, its there. In phpMyAdmin i can also just select categories_back_id, but not in symfony doctrine.
So i guess its the doctrine system?

How can i get this ID?

parent:

```
    /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="catorder", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $catorder;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
 */
private $description;


/**
 * One Content has Many Files.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\newspaper_subcategories", mappedBy="categoriesBack", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"subcatorder" = "ASC"})
 */
private $subcategories;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->subcategories = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

child:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="subcatorder", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $subcatorder;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="subdescription", type="text")
 */
private $subdescription;

/**
 *
 * Many files have One release.
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\newspaper_categories", inversedBy="subcategories")
 *
 */
private $categoriesBack;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent class if you call:

```
getSubcategories()
```

You should get a PersisentCollection containing your you children
By default your `ManyToOne` has a Lazy fetch. But if you loog through your subcaterories you'll be able to fetch them.

```
foreach ($object->getSubcategories() as $subcategories) {
  $id = $subcategories->getId()
 /* do stuff */
}
```

Is that your issue ? I didn't quite get your question so maybe I didn't get it, if that's the case could you reformulate a bit ? :)

Comment: No - not. I try to explain. I have a category table and subcategory table. Connected OneToMany. Means in the Subcategory table is created a column "categories_back_id" where is the ID from category to know wich subcategory is under wich category. I select the subcategory with ID in my query from subcategory table - o.k.. But i need also the ID from column "categories_back_id". But im not able to get this. If i write it in my query not working. Must i write a getter? Or is this lazy load Problem?''...SELECT sub.id, sub.categories_back_id FROM ...''

Comment: There is no issue doing it this way if you write `$subcategoryRepository->find($idSubcategory);` you should get it with all the field. If not it might be an issue on your entity.

Comment: O.K. - for other people:
in doctrine foreign key is not selected.
To do this use since Doctrine 2.2 
IDENTITY ()